# What is the fastest way to place blocks on Minecraft PS3?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

In Minecraft PS3, I am making a cool adventure map. However, the build involves lots of block placing. I seem to move slow; it will take a while. Luckily, the blocks are mostly just straight lines and moving fast will not cause too many blocks all over the place. What is the fastest way to place them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way to place blocks if to use a swiffness II potion. With this, you can move 40% faster.

Comment: Well, he's asking how to place blocks faster, not how to move faster. Usually, moving really really fast would bother you a lot.

Comment: @LuisUllman , I said most of them were stright. (I asked and answered my own question for the new Minecrafters)

Comment: Oh. didn't read the question all the way through.

Comment: Downside of this is if you're moving faster, even holding down the place button will not be able to keep up. If you're moving faster you'll end up leaving holes everywhere that you'll have to go and fix up later anyway.

Comment: @Ben it does on PS3. Again, this is teaching the new Minecrafters.

Comment: I understand that. However, you have to think about the content of your posts. Think about what exactly the "new Minecrafters" are actually going to be looking for. Are they going to be worried about their movement speed or are they going to be worrying about the Kamikaze Shrubs that keep destroying everything?

Comment: moving faster != placing blocks faster. even at normal speed moving backwards in a strait line on the PC placing block you tend to create gaps which requires you to backtrack and fill them in. this is because another factor when placing blocks when moving is where your aiming. i am unsure if the range or placing speed have increased on the PS3 but i would assume they are no different

Comment: @Ben i didn't think i'd here anyone but Yahtzee use the term *"Kamikaze Shrubs"*